# Get JSON facet_queries from Solr using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr

I am using Solr facets to split queried documents based on their category and their published date. I managed to write a query that returns what I want in JSON format. The result is something like this:

```
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "publ_tmstmp:[NOW/DAY-7DAYS TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]":0, //this week
      "publ_tmstmp:[NOW/DAY-1MONTH TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]":0, //this month
      "publ_tmstmp:[NOW/DAY-1YEAR TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]":30}, //this year
    "facet_fields":{
      "doc_typ_sht_nm":[
        "GUIDE",30,
        "ANNOUNCEMENT",0,
        "HEADLINE",0,
        "IMAGE",0,
        "LATEST_UPDATES",0]},
    "facet_dates":{},
    "facet_ranges":{}}}
```

I have no problem looping through the categories but I can't figure out how to do the same for the publication dates using Javascript/jQuery. I have tried several ways like:

```
result.facet_counts["facet_fields"]
result.facet_counts.facet_fields[0]
result.facet_counts.facet_queries["publ_tmstmp:[NOW/DAY-7DAYS TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]"]
var x in result.facet_counts.facet_queries
```

None of them work. Most of the time I get an "undefined". How can I iterate through my results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of it should work :-

For facet_fields -

```
console.log(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.doc_typ_sht_nm[0]);
console.log(data['facet_counts']['facet_fields']['doc_typ_sht_nm'][0]);
```

For facet_queries -

```
$.each(data['facet_counts']['facet_queries'], function(key, element){
    console.log(key+' : '+element);
});
```

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9tga/)

Comment: It works for fields but not for queries. If I do `alert(result['facet_counts']['facet_queries']);` it displays `[object Object]` but I can't loop inside it. What's weird is that `result['facet_counts']['facet_queries'].length` results in `undefined`.

Comment: i have added the loop in my answer already with key and value printed.

Comment: The thing is, it never enters the loop.

Comment: works for the example data you provide. edited the answer with jsfiddle link.

Comment: Dammit I can't believe how stupid I can be. It wasn't working for me because I was using the wrong query in my test app =). Thanks for your help!